# submit form performs ReST service and then submits

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit

I have a form that when you submit it first performs an Ajax call to a ReST service for validation

if the ReST returns success i want to then submit the form to the proper page via POST

html

```
<form id="purchaseForm">....</form>
```

jquery handles the form after validation using

```
$('#purchaseForm').submit(function(){

.... validation
then

data = ($('#purchaseForm').serialize());

          $.ajax({
              url: 'pp_order.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: data,
              cache: false,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(ret){
                 if (ret.Status == 'Failure'){
                    pp_error();

                }
                else{
                    $('#purchaseForm').attr('action', 'user_profile.php')
                    form[0].submit();
                }
              }

              });
});
```

Comment: you still have to validate the data on the actual post - so why do it twice?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand your question , what exactly are you asking ? Is it how to call the rest service ?

Comment: no the rest service calls fine and returns the ret.Status (Failure or Success).. If it returns Success i want the form to submit and post to user_profile.php ( a different page)

Comment: I would not separate the calls like you are attempting to do. That would leave your "proper page" open to invalid POST submissions. It is better to have one script to process the POST. If you need to communicate with third party APIs, do it via a cURL POST request from the server-side after processing the initial POST data.

Comment: @c.hill... Thanks.. I think That is sort of what i did, without curl.. I replaced submit with a button that triggers validation and then if valid jquery handles the submission.